# Why does my mesh have gaps in object mode that does not exist in edit mode?

Tags: mesh

Im new to blender and making a character, but at some point when i was fixing some of the vertexes i started getting gaps in my mesh even tho its all connected, what have i done wrong?

[image: Edit mode picture where its complete]

[image: Object mode with holes in the mesh]

[image]

Comment: How and why did need to "fix some of the vertices"? I think we'll need to see your Blend file to see what you have done. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/312348/edit) your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: The vertices are in the same location, but they are not merged.  Merge by distance.  You have some other modifier (maybe that armature?), or perhaps a shapekey, that is moving them apart.

Comment: @JohnEason I did just as you asked and uploaded it.

Comment: @Nathan i did as a turtorial said and merged a last point. Yes i realised the problem with the mesh when i had added my armature and tried to do animations, thats when the problem occured (Or when i noticed it).

Comment: You still have 8 duplicate vertices on your model. With your model selected, go into Edit mode hit A (All) to select the whole model then hit M > Merge by Distance. If you watch the bottom status bar while you're merging you will briefly see a message saying "Removed 8 vertices".

Comment: Nice thanks alot, is that the normal way to check if you messed up with vertices? So i knew when i mess up in the future.

Comment: Unless you Grab and move a vert and find another one underneath it's often impossible to tell if there are duplicates until you start animating, I usually check by trying to merge and seeing what's been reported as a matter of course. A favorite mistake is to select E (extrude) and then use right-click to cancel without moving the extrusion if you change your mind. This will **not** cancel the extrusion but will leave it in place and you won't be able to see the duplicates.